# Problem installing Tridion 2011 SP1 Hotfix Rollup 1 (HR1)

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I am trying to install User Interface Update 2012... Reading the documentation for the prerequisites section (in [sdllivecontent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/concept_59979CAA10334D61979C34C85FA7703A#addHistory=true&filename=ProductPrerequisitesRef.xml&docid=reference_8D62F291FEAE4B9F95A7493AD4CE4CB1)) I have seen that, first of all, I need to install the Hotfix Rollup 1. 
One of the first steps is to update CM database running the update SQL (in my case) script (HR_SQLSERVER.sql). Not without surprise, I find out that there are no rows updated. Then, when I execute the CM update installation wizard, it shows me the typical window with the repair, modify, uninstall buttons disabled (in another installations of HR#1 I have seen that when the HR#1 is already installed this window shows just this information).

This installation is being carried out in a Tridion SP1 Lab machine previously installed. So now, I have the doubt if the guy who installed this Lab tried to install the Hotfix rollup and maybe he could not finish the installation properly (?).

Could anyone know how to check whether the HR#1 is already installed (properly)? I read that is not possible to check this in any standard Tridion tool (although there is a  [HotfixManager extension](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/hotfixmanager.aspx) to use a priori):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037093/what-tridion-hotfixes-have-been-applied/11038501#11038501

But maybe, I could check the CM dll / jar versions? Or, in the case that something had remained inconsistent how could I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It indeed still remains an issue on how to find out what hotfixes have been installed, and basically HR1 is just a hotfix rollup.

Now first of all (I don't know any details but) the fact that the SQL script didn't need to update rows does not have to be an indication to anything wrong. It could be part of a hotfix which fixes common issues in the database which were non existing in yours, it's content related.

The Hotfix Manager extension, was created by a community member who was fed up with keeping a paper or digital list which kept being lost. Very useful, but not a requirement or part of the product unfortunately.

I believe that if the HR1 install was successful on the CM server, you should be able to find it back in the Programs and Features of your Control Panel. Still a failed installation could have left files behind without any thing in your Control Panel.

Then the next step would be to check the DLLs timestamps, if you take a look at the `..\Tridion\bin` folder you should see that most files have the same timestamp (within a range of a few days). If you see one DLL with a timestamp from months later, that is an indication of a hotfix. But to know for sure, you have to have details...

Comment: Nothing in the [...]\Tridion\bin folder, all the dlls have the same timestamp (more or less). There is nothing in the Programs and Features of Control Panel that reference this hotfix rollup. But indeed I continue seeing this weird installation wizard window (with buttons disabled).

Answer (score 2):

You can check the current version of the Content Manager in the Content Manager: tab SDL Tridion > About SDL TRidion

If Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 has been succesfully installed, you should have something like that:

```
Content Manager Explorer - Build 6.1.0.55920 
Content Manager - Build 6.1.0.997 
Update Version - Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - 1
```

Comment: I have the following (seems like HR1 is not installed):  Content Manager Explorer - Build 6.1.0.55920   Content Manager - Build 6.1.0.997   Update Version - SP1   Seems like HR#1 is not applied in the Tridion CM

Answer (score 1):

May be below trick works for you:

- Take a backup of your Tridion.ContentManager.config file
- Rename the Tridion.ContentManager.Config to some other name or delete it
- Try Installing Now
- It should work, and once finished, update the Tridion.ContentManager.config with the detla from the back up taken earlier.

Comment: Do you mean reinstalling the Content Manager HR1? After renaming Tridion.ContentManager.config file I continue seeing the window wizard installer with modify, repair, uninstall buttons disabled.

Comment: Yes I meant to say re-installing Content Manager HR 1 on CMS server. If it is still giving problem, I would recommend you to approach the SDL Tridion Support.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but also the same problem... I have tried another trick. I have launched the installation hotfix rollup with "run as" and I have used the mtsuser (the user who did the installation)... And now I am seeing a message like: "Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - 1 is already installed. Installation will now exit" although the same thing is showed when I check the current version (in CME: SDL Tridion>About SDL TRidion): "Update Version - SP1" and either nothing in Control Panel>Programs and Features.