# Is it necessary install UI 2012 on dedicated Publisher Server?

Tags: experience-manager

I'm installing a production environment of Tridion 2011 SP1 with UI 2012 SP1.

I have installed HR1 on CMS and Publishers servers and next I have installed UI on CMS, but when I tried to install UI on Publishers I obtain an error saying "its necessary to have installed Hotfix HR1 or later"

SDL Supports sent me this link: http://tridion.kb.sdl.com/kb/?ArticleId=5082&source=Article&c=12&cid=19#tab:homeTab:crumb:7:artId:5082 But right now I have the same version (6.1.0.314). Is that HR1 or HR2 version?

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Nuno, I have opened a Ticket and they reports me to the next page: http://tridion.kb.sdl.com/kb/?ArticleId=5082&source=Article&c=12&cid=19#tab:homeTab:crumb:7:artId:5082      But right now I have the same version (6.1.0.314). Is that HR1 or HR2 version?

Comment: Here is similar problem http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/814/problem-installing-tridion-2011-sp1-hotfix-rollup-1-hr1

Answer (score 2):

I do think you need to install it on the publishers - if for no other reason, it really is a good idea to have your servers consistent.

This error suggests that for some reason the publishers are not detecting HR1 installed - which is odd, I thought we checked the database for this. I would definitely open a ticket with Support, it might be an issue they've seen before.

Comment: Hi, in TDS_DB_INFO the version is set properly. I have opened a Support Ticket. Thank you